# EF6.1 Code First: 1:1 or zero issue with adding records and foreign keys

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-6.1

I have two entities, Executive and User. A User can be an Executive but an Executive HAS to be a User.

Executive:

```
public class Executive
{
    [Key]
    public int ExecutiveId { get; set; }

    // every executive is a user
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }...and so on
```

User:

```
 public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public int? ExecutiveId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ExecutiveId")]
    public virtual Executive Executive { get; set; }... and so on (note the nullable ExecutiveId)
```

CMSContext:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Executive>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.User)
            .WithOptional(s => s.Executive)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false); ... and so on
```

So, I added two Users and one executive in the initializer and one Executive like this:

```
 var users = new List<User>
        {
            new User{ EmailAddress="a@a.com", LastName="D'Amore", FirstName="Beau", PhoneNumber="888-555-1212"},          
            new User{ EmailAddress="b@b.com", LastName="Munster", FirstName="Herman", PhoneNumber="123-555-7878"}          
        };
        users.ForEach(s => context.Users.Add(s));
        context.SaveChanges();

  Executive exec = new Executive();
        exec.ExecutiveBlurb = "test blurb";
        exec.ExecutiveTitle = "President";
        exec.ProfilePictureContent = new Content { ContentBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("c:\\exec.jpg"), AddedDate = DateTime.Now, AddedByUserId = 1 };
        exec.ProfileSidePictureContent = new Content { ContentBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("c:\\exec2.jpg"), AddedDate = DateTime.Now, AddedByUserId = 1 };
        exec.UserId = 1;
        exec.User = users.Where(x => x.UserId == 1).First();
        exec.ExecutiveSections = context.ExecutiveSections.Where(x => x.SectionName == "Executive Team" && x.SectionName == "Acquisitions").ToList();
        context.Executives.Add(exec);
```

Thing is, the Executive is created after the User (as it should be since it's 1:1 or 0) But the User never gets the ExecutiveId set... doesn't EF handle the foreign keys automagically? Like, when I add objectA to objectB, normally, setting A to have B as it's foreign key sets B to have A as it's reciprocating property... I'm missing something with the 1:1 or 0 thing.
any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Entity Framework with a 1:0..1 relationship, or any other kind of one-to-one relationship, both entities on each side of the relationship must share a primary key. For whichever side is dependent -- with required-optional, it would be the optional side -- the primary key property is also the foreign key.

In your case, you have some conflicting/redundant annotations and fluent API calls, but fluent API takes precedence, so `Executive.UserId` and `User.ExecutiveId` are being ignored. The `Executive` you created should end up with `exec.User.UserId == exec.ExecutiveId`.

This makes sense because you'll never have an `Executive` without a `User`, and there will never be more than one `Executive` tied to the same `User`, so an `Executive` wouldn't need a separate primary key.

*https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620#RequiredToOptional*

Comment: Could you say which are the conflicting and redundant annotations, please? I'd really like to learn this...

Comment: Your `modelBuilder.Entity<Executive>()...` is almost the same as adding `[ForeignKey("User")]` to 'Executive.ExecutiveId` (except for the cascade delete setting, I think), so your other `[ForeignKey(..)]` attributes are ignored.